# How can I limit the performance of sandboxed Java code?

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, sandbox

I'm working on a multi-user Java webapp, where it is possible for clients to use the webapp API to do potentially naughty things, by passing code which will execute on our server in a sandbox.

For example, it is possible for a client to write a tight while(true) loop that impacts the performance of other clients.

Can you guys think of ways to limit the damage caused by these sorts of behaviors to other clients' performance?

We are using Glassfish for our application server.

Comment: Can you elobarate this sort of webapp API a little more ?

Comment: Seems like the answer to this could come in a book - consisting of 3 volumes.

Comment: I do not understand it - can clients submit (Java) code your app will execute?

Comment: Essentially yes, clients can execute sandboxed Java code. Don't tell me that's a bad idea, because it wasn't mine :).  I was thinking about perhaps using synchronization so that the host could take a lock to prevent clients from using their resources.

Comment: Andrew, that may well be the case, but can you tell me what's on the book's dust jacket at least?

Comment: @fun, I believe Andrew is suggesting The Art Of Computer Programming, which is currently in four volumes.

Comment: @Thorbjørn  I suspected that '3' was being a bit optimistic (when I plucked that figure out of the air).  ;)

Comment: @fun.bat  If the client code is sand-boxed, that reduces the options that can be used to cause problems.  I think that information should be edited into the question rather than left as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem show that there is no way that a computer can reliably identify code that will not terminate.

The only way to do this reliably is to execute your code in a separate JVM which you then ask the operating system to shut down when it times out.   A JVM not timing out can process more tasks so you can just reuse it.

Comment: The problem isn't so much that they can write a loop that never ends, it's that they essentially tie up an entire CPU core doing that. A never-ending loop is fine if e.g. it spends most of the time just waiting for data. I'm more interested in finding a way to slow down a client's loop.

Comment: +1 for the separate JVM. Even if you manage to somehow evenly distribute the thread cpu-time, there's still memory allocation you have to deal with.

Comment: @fun, you need the operating system to do that.  The JVM cannot.

Answer (score 2):

One more idea would be byte-code instrumentation. Before you load the code sent by your client, manipulate it so it adds a short sleep in every loop and for every method call (or method entry).

This avoids clients clogging a whole CPU until they are done. Of course, they still block a Thread object (which takes some memory), and the slowing down is for every client, not only the malicious ones. Maybe make the first some tries free, then scale the waiting time up with each try (and set it down again if the thread has to wait for other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Modern day app servers use Thread Pooling for better performance. The problem is that one bad apple can spoil the bunch. What you need is an app server with one thread or maybe process per request. Of course there are going to be trade offs. but the OS will handle making sure that processing time gets allocated evenly.
NOTE: After researching a little more what you need is an engine that will create another process per request. If not a user can either cripple you servlet engine by having servlets with infinite loops and then posting multiple requests. Or he could simply do a System.exit in his code and bring everybody down.

Comment: In fact, the threads can be assigned lower priority than the rest of the application (the server's core execution threads) so that the server's core functionality is never starved of CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parent thread to launch each request in a separate thread as suggested already, but then monitor the CPU time used by the threads using the ThreadMXBean class.  You could then have the parent thread kill any threads that are misbehaving.  This is if, of course, you can establish some kind of reasonable criteria for how much CPU time a thread should or should not be using.  Maybe the rule could be that a certain initial amount of time plus a certain additional amount per second of wall clock time is OK?

I would make these client request threads have lower priority than the thread responsible for monitoring them.